# how to let dc only go one way

Tags: usb, switches, diodes

I'm planning to make a circuit that lets me switch my keyboard and mouse between 2 computers.
this shows me how to do it.
https://hackaday.com/2016/11/12/diy-kvm-switch-lets-you-use-one-keyboard-and-mouse-with-multiple-computers/

but people were saying it not a good idea to have USB power going back into another pc.
I think I was read you can use a diode. I don't know what cables the diodes need to be connected to.
ty for reading.
this will all so be my first time doing this type of stuff.

any suggestions on changing anything I'm all ears :p.

Comment: Why would you need a circuit for that? I use (the 4-port version) of this box: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sharing-Manual-Printer-Scanner-Keyboard/dp/B01AJP7FLC  It's a metal box with two push-button switches. There are **no electronics** inside. It is the same as if plugging the mouse and keyboard into the PC you want to use by hand. To switch keyboard and mouse simultaneously, use it with a USB hub (that's what I do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't attempt the diode solution. The commenters are correct in that wiring the two power supplies together like that is likely to cause problems; I've myself seen a PC that won't shut down properly if back-fed 5V through USB from a bad hub.

What I would suggest is connect both the grounds together, but connect only one of the power supplies. That obviously requires that PC to be on, so you can't use the gizmo if only the other one is on.

An alternative that doesn't have that limitation is to use an externally powered hub on the side after the switch, and connect NEITHER of the power lines but BOTH the ground lines.

Comment: ty man well do :D now to get the parts :p